# Как сделать DialogFragment со своей разметкой и повесить слушатель нажатий на элемент разметки?

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment, android-dialog

У меня есть `DialogFragment` в который я передаю свой кастомный `layout` и вот этот `layout` у меня содержит 2 кнопки(Которые соответствуют стилю приложения). Как получить к ним доступ?

**Вот так выглядит мой DialogFragment класс :**

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

final String LOG_TAG = "MyDialog";
int layout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    Bundle args = this.getArguments();
    layout = args.getInt("layout");
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(layout)
            .setCancelable(true);

    return adb.create();
}

public void dismissDialog(final MyDialog dialog, int daleyTime) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, daleyTime);
}

public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyDialog: onDismiss");
}

public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onCancel(dialog);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyDialog: onCancel");
}

public static MyDialog newInstance(int layout) {
    MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("layout", layout);
    myDialog.setArguments(args);

    return myDialog;
}
}
```

**Как установить лисенер на кнопках layout который я передаю в `DialogFragment`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

    Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setListener(...); 

    builder.setView(view);
    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: Вроде все понятно, вот только зачем `setView(view);` ? Я ж так понимаю, что вью нашли, лисенер поставили, зачем делать `setView(view);`? И еще один вопрос, у меня этот диалог используют несколько классов, и только один класс передает `layout` с кнопками... Мне вот интересно, будет ли вылетать код при таком подходе, если передать активити без кнопок... Как инфлейтор будет искать их... Скорее всего вылетет... Можно это обойти?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, 1) Ну так засетить эту вьюху диалогу нужно, в вашем коде тоже сетится layout  2) Обойти можно так:  `Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button); if( button != null)
    button.setListener(...);`